# API - Client - JSONP - Not returning https request to client

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, https, jsonp

I recently updated my Flask application to https. I have an ajax call in the application which posts data to a http api. The upgrade to https on the client application has broken this request. There no sign of the request being seen on the api (I have a print statement).

```
         # client application             

         $.ajax({
            url: "//api.com/add/id/{{id}}",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                active: checkbox,
                user_name: name
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });


        # response from the api

        return '{0}({1})'.format(callback, {'response': 'success'})
```

Do I need to udpate the callback or the request in any way going from http to https in the client? Thanks

Comment: i noticed that you set the type options to "POST" which dosnt affect the fact the JSONP alwasy GET, so i think you expecting the request to be handled as POST while it is GET request

Comment: the api endpoint accepts both GET and POST - so it shouldnt matter

Comment: if the api donst use https, Google Chrome, by default, blocks insecure content on secure pages, so this may be the issue ?

Comment: Is there a way to stop the browser from blocking it?